# Load data in custom form by using Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I searched the whole web and I couldn't found any good topic which expose the proper way to do it.

I have a very simple web which I developed using Kentico 9 CMS. This web only contains two subpages and a header to navigate between those.

The "Home" subpage contains a *custom form* which remains connected to a SQL table which is populated every time you press submit with certain data.

[image]

On the other hand, the other page, shows the stored data by using a *custom web part* which connects to the DB by using **BizFormItemProvider** and this object is used as a layer to binding the data in a  control.

[image]

Now is my point. If you see, there is a button to "Edit" a certain row and my intention is to Redirect to "Home" (which contains the form) and sending via QueryString the ID of the row attempted to edit.

**I was unable to understand how can you re-fill the form with its data using an ID**.

Maybe because I never worked with a CMS before, I'm looking the development such as pure ASP.NET and it could not be the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Custom

Given that your solution uses a **custom form** for entering the data, as well as a **custom web part** for listing the stored data, you will need to use a custom solution to handle the editing of data, as well.

In the custom webpart on the Home page, in a load event, you can retrieve the form data and set the values on the form controls.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure that the form is not being posted back,
    // to prevent entered data from being overwritten
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Get the form item ID from the query string
        var personId = QueryHelper.GetInteger("personId", 0);
        if(personId > 0)
        {
            // Get the biz form item, and set form control values
            var bizFormItem = BizFormItemProvider.GetItem(personId, "customFormClassName");
            txtFirstName.Text = bizFormItem.GetStringValue("FirstName", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, when **Submit** is clicked, you can update the existing form item with the new data

```cs
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the form item ID from the query string
    var personId = QueryHelper.GetInteger("personId", 0);
    if(personId > 0)
    {
        // Retrieve the existing biz form item,
        // and update it from the form control values
        var bizFormItem = BizFormItemProvider.GetItem(personId, "customFormClassName");
        bizFormItem.SetValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        bizFormItem.Update();
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code for inserting a new form item...
    }
}
```

### The Kentico way

You should really consider using the Kentico form engine for accomplishing this task. Instead of using a custom form for entering the data, use the built-in **On-line form** webpart.

[The benefits are numerous](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Forms), such as:

- Ability to set the form layout through the CMS, and use alternative layouts
- Automatic confirmation email to the submitter of the form, as well as notification emails to the administrators

To accomplish your task, you can [customise the On-line form webpart](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Customizing+web+parts) to support loading of existing data.
In the `bizform.ascx.cs` file, add code to the `SetupControl` method:

```cs
protected void SetupControl()
{
    if (StopProcessing)
    {
        // Existing code...
    }
    else
    {
        // Existing code...

        // Get the form item ID from the query string
        var personId = QueryHelper.GetInteger("personId", 0);
        if(personId > 0)
        {
            // Get the biz form item, and set form control values
            var bizFormItem = BizFormItemProvider.GetItem(personId, "customFormClassName");
            if(bizFormItem != null)
            {
                // Set the item ID
                viewBiz.ItemID = bizFormItem.ItemID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will automagically switch the form to **Edit** mode, instead of **Insert** mode, as soon as you set the `ItemID` property. Clicking the Submit button will save changes on the existing form item.
You will not need to worry about validation in your code, and inserting data will still work.

Comment: Your response was awesome! Thanks a lot. I have to dig a big more into "The Kentico Way" as you said. Thanks once again...

Answer (score 1):

Is this a contact form that you are using Kenticos built in form application for, or is it a custom form? If it is a custom form you can create a transformation with a link that will contain the ID. If it is a biz form, you can still create a transformation in Page Types (create a new page type and select "The page type is only a container without custom fields"), then write a [custom query](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Loading+data+using+custom+queries) to get the biz form data, and use a repeater to display the data with that transformation.